# Pass Ilogger on non-controller models

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, nlog

I am creating an app in .net core and I'm trying to output a log.

I was able to log output from the controller and I also want to log output from the model, which is shown below.

Unfortunately, I don't know what to pass as arguments to the constructor. My guess is the same `Ilogger<controller>` as the controller, but I would like to know if there is a correct way.

Thanks in advance.

Controller:

```
public class SampleController : Controller {
    public readonly ILogger<SampleController > _logger;
    public SampleController (ILogger<SampleController > logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }


    [HttpGet("[action]")]
    public string FindSample()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("FindSample Start");

        // ***** Is it necessary to carry over the log of the sample controller to a much lower DAO from here? *****
        var model = new SampleModel(_logger);
        var result = model.Find();

        _logger.LogInformation("FindSample End");
        return result;
    }
}
```

Model:

```
    public class SampleModel
    {
        public readonly ILogger<SampleController> _logger;
        public SampleModel(ILogger<SampleController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public string Find()
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("FindModel Start");

            var dao = new SampleDao(_logger);
            var code = dao.GetCode();

            _logger.LogInformation("FindModel End");
            return code;
        }
    }
```

Dao:

```
    public class SampleDao
    {
        public readonly ILogger<SampleController> _logger;
        public SampleContext SampleContext;

        // ***** Should I pass it as an argument forever? *****
        public SampleDao(ILogger<SampleController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            if (SampleContext == null)
            {
                SampleContext = new SampleContext();
            }
        }

        public string GetCode()
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("GetCode Start");

            var code = SampleContext.SampleTable.FirstOrDefault().code;

            _logger.LogInformation("GetCode End");
            return code;
        }
    }
```

Comment: By default, `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)` injects `Console`, `Debug` and `EventSource` logger providers.  So I think you can safely inject `ILogger<>` through constructor injection anywhere after that?

Comment: You should ideally be injecting all those tightly coupled instantiations via constructor injection along with the logger

Comment: thank you for your comment.
I'm sorry, but I'm translating and viewing the comments, so I may not have understood it correctly.
The provider is added etc. referring to the following URL.
In the reference URL, I think that there is a description of "AboutModel"
I can not understand what should be passed as an argument of the constructor because there is no case where this AboutModel is new. . .

https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should pass as a generic argument the class in which the logger is being injected. So you should use:

**In your Dao**

```cs
ILogger<SampleDao> logger
```

**In your Model**

```cs
ILogger<SampleModel> logger
```

For more information you could check:
[Logging in ASP.NET core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I also saw the reference URL,
If my understanding is not enough, and it is actually new, the model constructor does not know where to bring the logger from and pass in the arguments. . .

Comment: Okk. Now I get it. The model is obviously not injected via dependency injection but created via new() instead. You could use your approach and use the Controller but it would tightly couple your model with the Controller class, which is awfull. The other thing you could try is inject two instances of the ILogger in the controller one of type ```SampleController``` and another one of type ```SampleModel``` and then when you create your model inside the controller pass the instance of the ILogger to the constructor of the Model

Comment: Does it mean that you do not usually use new?
At another site, I also saw something like "services.AddTransient" and so on.
In that case, it is a clue that all models and Dao have to be registered.
If you answer it, would it be as follows?

public SampleController (ILogger <SampleController> logger, ILogger <SampleModel> modelLogger, ILogger <SampleDao> daoLogger)

var model = new SampleModel (modelLogger, daoLogger);

I'm sorry if it has become rude English by translation

Comment: I got confused at first when I first answered. But I ALWAYS use new for models. stuff like services are the ones that are usually created via dependency injection but stuff like models should be created by hand with new

Comment: It seems strange to add Model or Dao to a service, right?
In such a case, is it taking over the logger to the lower layer as mentioned above?

After all, I do not know what to do, but for the time being, since the log is still output as it is, I will proceed as it is. . .
Thank you very much.

Comment: A model is not meant to be injected so it would be really weird.

Comment: After all, I also think that it is quite strange.
For the controller, in the same way as before
In the case of models, create a base model and
"LogManager.LoadConfiguration (" nlog.config "). GetLogger (GetType (). ToString ());"
And the controller's logger separately from the form of holding the logger.